# Member's verification

Tags: trello, trello-organization, verification

How do I verify whether someone who I invited to my organisation through Trello is really who the photo says they are? There is no link to the email address on Trello so it is really difficult to know whether they are really genuine.

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way round. You should ask people for their screen names in an email (not saying emails cannot be forged, it's simply that inviting total strangers to your organization is not reasonable).